# How to use Tideways on own server?

Tags: php, profiling, xhprof

Tideways is a PHP profiling extension (further development of XHProf, working with PHP 7) and provides also on [tideways.io](https://tideways.io) a service for analyzing the profiling results.

Currently I don't need the web GUI and want to use for a PHP 7 project a combination [Tideways PHP module](https://github.com/tideways/php-profiler-extension) & [XHProf UI](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof).

I installed the module as described in the [installation manual](https://tideways.io/profiler/docs/setup/installation):

```
echo 'deb http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qafoo-profiler/packages debian main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tideways.list
wget -qO - https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qafoo-profiler/packages/EEB5E8F4.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tideways-php tideways-daemon
```

moved the automatically created `tideways.ini` from `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available` to `/etc/php/mods-available`, make a symlink to it in the FPM `conf.d` folder (`ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/tideways.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-tideways.ini`), and configured as follows:

```
extension=tideways.so
;tideways.api_key=
tideways.sample_rate=25
tideways.framework=zend2
tideways.auto_prepend_library=0
```

<sup>Btw. I'm wondering, that there is no config key for the output target (Like `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` for the Xdebug Profiler). Is is a hardcoded value? Where is the output saved?</sup>

The extension seems to be installed and ready for using:

[image]

**How to start using the Tideways PHP Profiler Extension?**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the extension without the product (which you should think about again, the smallest plan at 49€/month are a great deal compared to setting this up yourself and maintaining it) then you need to write some code yourself.

At the end of a request, when you call $data = tideways_disable(); you need to store this information on disk in the same format that xhprof UI requires. See this page on our website with more details on how to get this working: https://tideways.io/profiler/xhprof-for-php7-php5.6

Comment: Thank you for this. The projects own documentation contains incorrect commands (i.e. `tideways_xhprof_enable()` and `tideways_xhprof_disable()`) which meant all I could ever get was fatal errors. Remove the `_xhprof` token and it all works :)

Comment: yes, we have seprated the tideways extension that works with our SaaS and the xhprof only extension from each other.

This is why our documentation shows the new `tideways_xhprof_enable()` which is available from this PHP extension: https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension